# LinkButton is not properly triggered

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I'm going crazy about making this code to work. I got a simple link button that I add to a panel. When I click on the link, it's like something is trigger (whole page refresh and my link button disappear) but when I debug it, I never enter my DownloadItems function.

```
LinkButton linkTest = new LinkButton();
linkTest.ID = "ID";
linkTest.Click += new EventHandler(DownloadItems);
linkTest.Text = "Test";
```

In another page, everything is working great but I can't put my finger on it :s

Comment: Do you recreate the LinkButton on every postback?

Comment: Actually no...damn it. I wasn't reloading because I didn't wanted to lose my dropdownlist selection. Thanks

Comment: add more code. it help to find out exact problem